# virtual box guest o.s not working

Tags: networking

I  have  window server 2003 as a host on virtual box and  two window 7 as a guest o.s.I tried to run both window 7 at the same time but it is showing error"A critical error has occured  while running  the virtual machine and the machine execution has stopped ". How can I fix this error?

Comment: What programming language are you using to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not using any programming  language , just need to work both window 7 running at the same time.I am measuring the cpu,hdd,memory consumption on the number of virtual machines.

Comment: Have you read the [FAQ]? This is a site for *programming* questions.

Answer (score 0):

the reason that you have this error is because either you ran out of Ram or that your processor is unable to keep up with both machines which virtualbox has a built in trigger to keep your computer safe the only way to fix this is not software but hardware

Comment: You know this for a fact? Or are you just guessing, because the error above says nothing about running out of resources. Also, your statement about keeping your computer "safe" is plain wrong. If the hardware itself were somehow in danger (which only comes from high temperature events), the main OS would shut down too.

Comment: I am not sure if it is  the hardware issue,I have installed  three window xp as a guest o.s on virtual box that has window server 2003 as a host.It worked for me and I was able to  measure  CPU,HDD,Memory consumption on those virtual machines.